# What are the best practice in drilling anchor screw holes in right locations?

Tags: drill, drywall-anchor, measuring

I am setting up several stations side by side that look like this:

[image]

For each station I have to install a mirror that has two hooks behind it and look like this:

[image: The other side or mirror]

Those hooks are supposed to hang on anchor screws heads that have to be installed in the wall. The problem I am facing is that I have to locate the right locations on the wall where to drill the holes for drywall anchor screws, so that:

1. I drill the holes correctly the first time because (I) I can't drill holes close to each other to fix small alignment issues without patching up the previous hole; AND (II) I can't drill holes few inches to left or right because then I would create a gap between stations that are already correctly installed.
2. The mirror needs to be high enough from the floor so that it would almost "sit on the table" and be next to shelves on the left.
3. the hooks in the mirror would hang on drywall anchor screw heads.

So far I tried locate location for drywall anchors by using measuring tape. However, the holes were off by a 1 cm and this does not seem feasible to install multiple stations.

Another solution I thought about is to get a huge clear plexiglass sheet, hold it against mirror to mark where are the hook holes. Drill them on plexiglass. Then put the Plexiglas against the wall and mark the holes on the wall. Note, the station and/or mirror do not have perfect 90 degree angle on the lower left corner. So I may have to create such template per mirror which could turn out wasteful for a such one time work.

**I am wondering if there is a more elegant solutions than to use Plexiglas approach?**

Like, would one one of the laser leveling/measuring devices help here (if so what features to look for in such device)? Adjustable aftermarket anchor screws or hooks that I could use? Anything else?

Comment: I would like to know if you found an answer to your problem, was it one of these?

Answer (score 2):

Level, laser or bubble. If the mirrors are all the same, and the mounting location is the same, you could use a template based on the location from the ceiling down. Mark your line horizontally on all the walls, then place the mirror on the wall where you would like it hung, then mark the edges of the mirror on both sides on the horizontal mark. Once that is done, measure in from your mark on each side, place your X, drill your hole and install your anchors. Other options would include cable hangers, saw-tooth...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a template:

Try this:

On the back of one mirror exactly 1 inch above the hook point put in a screw.  Let it stick out 1/2"  Repeat for all the hook points.

now rub the head of each screw with lip stick.

Use a sheet of plywood or strand board, and cut it to the same size as the mirror.

Put the mirror face down on the floor.

Clamp a 1" wide board to the bottom edge of the mirror.

With a friend line up the plywood with the mirror, but with the bottom edge against the 1" board.  The 1"  off set lifts the template by the same 1" you offset the screws in the mirror.

Press firmly against the screws, transfering the lipstick to the plywood.

Drill holes the size of your anchor pilot holes in the plywood on the lipstick marks.

Remove the clamp board, and verify that the holes line up with the points on the back of the mirror.

Using a laser level, set a temporary ledger board that will support the template still while  you drill your pilot holes.

Drill one set of holes, set your anchors and set your first mirror.

Set your ledger boards for the entire wall.

Repeat.

Remove ledger boards.  Patch the holes the ledger boards screws made.

Answer (score 0):

Simple redneck method:

1. Hold the frame level in the desired location.
2. Apply firm but gentle pressure over the hooks. This should produce a light dimple in the dry wall.
3. Using a finish nail on Phillips head screwdriver driver, make a center punch so the drill bit doesn't wander.
4. Using a drill bit slightly smaller than the anchor, drill your hole.
5. Gently tap the anchor into position.